# Solve dynamic system using Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

**Problem Statement**

Consider the following dynamic system,
[image: Dynamic System]
Where,
[image]

K=4 and m=4.

Find out the value of x(t) at the given value of t=2, with initial condition $x(0)$ and $\dot x(0)$, using the Euler method for numerical integration.

So far, I solved Euler method for differential equation. How could I solve it for dynamic system?

Comment: Your system seems a bit strange...  The first equation just becomes $x'(t) = x'(t)$, and the second $ x''(t)=-\frac km x(t)+\frac 1m F$. The dependence on $x'$ is only expressed through $F$.

Comment: What was the system you solved using Euler's method?
$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t) = v(t) \\ v ' (t) = -\frac km x(t)+ \frac 1m F
\end{cases} 
$$ ?

Comment: It looks like the [harmonic oscillator with a step input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Step_input), where we study the movement of a mass $m$ on a spring with elastic constant $k$ and with an external force $F$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes I am looking for the solution of the system of differential equations as you rightly mentioned in your second comment.